# Rails nested form on HABTM: how to prevent duplicate entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation, activerecord

I have simple app with 3 tables in DB and 'many-to-many' relationships.

```
# Model Employee
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :phonenumbers
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :phonenumbers, :allow_destroy => true
   attr_accessible :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name, :phonenumbers_attributes
end

# Model Phonenumber
class Phonenumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
  attr_accessible :number
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees
end
```

I have 'employees_phonenumbers' join-table with 'employee_id' and 'phonenumber_id' columns.

```
# View
<%= form_for @employee, :url => { :action => :create } do |f| %>

<%= f.label "Last name"   %>
<%= f.text_field :last_name   %>

<%= f.label "First name"   %>
<%= f.text_field :first_name  %>

<%= f.label "Middle name"   %>
<%= f.text_field :middle_name %>

<%= f.fields_for :phonenumbers do |phonenumber| %>
    <%= phonenumber.label "Phone number" %>
    <%= phonenumber.telephone_field :number %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>

# Controller
def create
  @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
  @employee.save ? (redirect_to :action => :index) : (render "new")
end
```

Now if I create a user: 'John' with phone number '555', it's OK.

But if I want to create a user 'Larry' with the same phone number '555', there's a dublicate of '555' entry in the DB.

How do I prevent this?

**UPDATE:** My logic is: If there is number '555', then do not create a new one, use existing. If there is no such a number, then create a new one and use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in employee.rb:

```
before_save :get_phonenumbers


  def get_phonenumbers
    self.phonenumbers = self.phonenumbers.collect do |phonenumber|
      Phonenumber.find_or_create_by_number(phonenumber.number)
    end
  end
```

I have found its working

Answer (score 4):

You can use rails validation to check uniqueness of record.

In your model **phonenumber.rb** put following line,

```
validates_uniqueness_of :column_name
```

It will ensure that **Phonenumber** will have unique phone_numbers only.

Now in controller you can check phone_number from params and if number is already exist then we will delete nested attributes fron params so that Phonenumber record wont generate.

```
 def create
   @phone_number = Phonenumber.where(:number=>params[:employee][:phonenumber][:number])
   if @phone_number.any?
      params[:employee].delete(:phonenumber)
      @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
      if @employee.save?
        @employee.phonenumber = @phone_number.first
        redirect_to :action => :index
      else
        render "new"
      end
   else
     @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
     @employee.save ? (redirect_to :action => :index) : (render "new")
   end
 end
```

Comment: My logic is:
If there is number '555', then do not create a new one, use existing.
If there is no such a number, then create a new one and use it.

Comment: you can can check the presence for phone number before creating the record. For this you can check telephone_number value form params. check parmas value using binding.pry and do changed accordingly in params. But for now, let me check first so that i'll give you code.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check it and let me know if any error  occurred.