# Find Or Create Rails Nested Attribute By Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, constructor, nested-attributes

I have a Model called `Example` that `accepts_nested_attributes_for NestedExample`.

When I create a new `Example` Model I can also create NestedExamples:

```
params = { :name => 'Example 1', :nested_example_attributes => { :name => 'Nested Example 1' } }


Example.find_or_create_by_name params
```

This is all working fine. However, I rather than creating a new `NestedExample` every time, I would like Rails to perform a `find_or_create_by_name` on the `NestedExample` model, so that in the above situation, if there is already a `NestedModel` with a name of `Nested Example 1`, it will be used, rather than a new instance of `NestedExample` with the same name.

My current result:

```
params_1 = { :name => 'Example 1', :nested_example_attributes => { :name => 'Nested Example 1' } }

params_2 = { :name => 'Example 2', :nested_example_attributes => { :name => 'Nested Example 1' } }


example_1 = Example.find_or_create_by_name params_1
example_2 = Example.find_or_create_by_name params_2

puts example_1.nested_example.id == example_2.nested_example.id # Should be true
```

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954411/rails-nested-form-on-habtm-how-to-prevent-dublicates/16954530#16954530

i hope this will help you.

Comment: `Example` and `NestedExample` has a `has_one`/`belongs_to` association, respectively? Honestly, it would really help if you weren't trying to obfuscate the true names of the models, IMHO.

Comment: It's a pedantic point, but I believe your final line should read: `puts example_1.nested_example.id == example_2.nested_example.id`

Comment: @zeantsoi This requirement, I think, is not possible for `has_one`/`belongs_to` association. It will just end up updating `example_id` from NestedExample removing reference from `example_1` to `example_2`

Comment: @zeantsoi Actually it's a `has_many through` relationship, but I thought that would complicate the question.

Comment: @zeantsoi Not pedantic at all. I've corrected the error.

Comment: Try to use Example.find_or_create_by_name_and_nested_example

Comment: @IvanShamatov That's wishful thinking ;)