# Duplicate models being created with Find_or_Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a find_or_create function (something similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956408/791381)) in my app where one post has many locations (through a locations_posts table). Unfortunately the code seems to execute, find the right record and then go on to create a new one anyway, resulting in record duplication. Any idea why this may the occurring?

*Post.rb*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save :get_locations

    # ===============
    # = Before Save = 
    # ===============




  def get_locations
    self.locations = self.locations.collect do |location|
      Location.find_or_create_by(name: location[:name])
    end
  end


    # =================
    # = Associations =
    # =================    

    has_many :location_post
    has_many :locations, :through => :location_post

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
```

*posts_controller.rb*

```
class PostsController < ::Blogit::ApplicationController    

...

def create
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(valid_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: t(:blog_post_was_successfully_created, scope: 'blogit.posts')
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

*Logs*

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"n4s...uAHATBRG1Nk=", "post"=>{"title"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
et", "body"=>"Consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in diam in massa aliquet venenatis. Donec eleifend sed magna rutrum sagittis.", "locations_attributes"=>{"1402420506265"=>{"name"=>"London", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: _destroy
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN

  Location Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "locations".* FROM "locations"  WHERE "locations"."name" = 'London' LIMIT 1

  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "blog_posts" ("blogger_id", "blogger_type", "body", "created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $
5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["blogger_id", 1], ["blogger_type", "User"], ["body", "Consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in diam in massa aliquet ven
enatis. Donec eleifend sed magna rutrum sagittis."], ["created_at", "2014-06-10 17:15:09.564257"], ["title", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"], [
"updated_at", "2014-06-10 17:15:09.564257"]]

  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "locations" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-06-10 1
7:15:09.566659"], ["name", "London"], ["updated_at", "2014-06-10 17:15:09.566659"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "location_posts" ("created_at", "location_id", "post_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)  [["created_at", "
2014-06-10 17:15:09.568250"], ["location_id", 376], ["post_id", 83], ["updated_at", "2014-06-10 17:15:09.568250"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "location_posts" ("created_at", "location_id", "post_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)  [["created_at", "
2014-06-10 17:15:09.571852"], ["location_id", 1], ["post_id", 83], ["updated_at", "2014-06-10 17:15:09.571852"]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Show the self.locations content in the method get_locations please.

Comment: Hi @JorgedelosSantos, sorry not sure what you mean?

Comment: Show the content of the self object before doing the get_location loop. self.inspect and put the content.

Comment: self.inspect before doing the self.locations function yields this `#<Blogit::Post id: nil, title: "This is a test post", body: "This is a test postThis is a test postThis is a te...", blogger_id: 1, blogger_t
ype: "User", comments_count: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, coverphoto_file_name: nil, coverphoto_content_type: nil, coverphoto_file_si
ze: nil, coverphoto_updated_at: nil, locations_linked: nil>` - hmm... no location attributes.

Comment: Removing the before save seems to be a solution as long as its callinga relation, and will return all persisted objects.

Comment: Hi @JorgedelosSantos. Removing the before save stops the duplication but then the find_or_create method doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need the find. The location will be finded or created if you define the name as primary key for location. Read the answer.

Comment: Thanks Jorge but I don't believe changing it to name is the solution (I cannot have two primary keys), and I know doing so affects performance. The primary key is the ID.

Comment: The you have to pass the key in order to find the related location for rails. If you don't have it because it's new rails will create a new one automatically.

Comment: That `get_locations` method doesnt make sense to me. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` should do all the work for you, creating new locations and updating existing locations. What exactly is the problem you have after removing `get_locations`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, your problem got my going down a rabbit-hole. So, let me recap, your premise was simple: before saving the post you want to make sure that if locations already exist in the database, you use those instead. It sounds simple enough, *and* it used to work. In rails 3.x something

So I recreated your example, and lo and behold: I got doubles everywhere.

Somehow it always remembered the original locations added, and then it dawned on me: it immediately adds the new location to the `location_posts` as well, and when I then change `locations`, I am actually adding *new* locations to `location_posts`.

So rest assured: the `find_or_create_by` works perfectly :)

So after a lot of trial and error, I was able to fix this as follows:

```
 before_save :reuse_existing_locations

 def reuse_existing_locations
  new_locations = locations.map do |location |
    if location.new_record?
      new_loc = Location.find_by(name: location.name)
      new_loc.present? ? new_loc : location.dup
    else
      location.dup
    end
  end

  self.location_posts.reset
  self.locations.replace( new_locations)
end
```

So the key-take aways:

- `dup` (copy) all elements, or otherwise when I do the replace or reset, the list will be empty
- reset the `location_posts` so it is empty, *before* inserting the "new" locations
- use `replace` to replace the current array of locations with the new one (otherwise it will also just add)

I have a feeling this is a rails-bug but not sure of that. At least it got a lot more difficult than it was before.

Comment: Perfect! Dropped in no problem and worked first time. May do some research into whether it is indeed a bug. Thanks @nathanvda

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you can remove the before_save as long as it seems not to be working:

self.locations is a relation that calls a relation, collecting all existing items inside an active record array. If the items are not in the table, he won't create a new one as long as it won't find anything that's not persisted.

The nested params are the one in charge of doing the find or create for the location. As long as you define a primary key that is passed to the post model from the controller.

This is the workflow for the nested:

- controller creates a new model with the params, and a new instance of
  related model with the nested params and begins a transaction.
- If the
  first model is saved the relation is saved over the existing id, or creates a new one.
- If the first model or the second model fails, the transaction rolls back and nothing is saved.

If the nested params is not creating the location by itself (or updating if existing) it means that you are not passing the correct params, or you are not sending the primary key.

Comment: Hi @Jorge I'm not sure I understand. I'm declaring has_many :locations through location_posts (see above). Update_only as a nested attributes param also did not work. any other ideas?

Comment: accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :update_only => true

Comment: Hi Jorge, yes I tried this but there has been no change. Duplicates are still being created.

Comment: You have duplication in your join table or in the locations table?

Comment: It creates a duplication in the 'locations' table (same name but different ID's) and then creates 2 join records - one for each of the ID's?